# Send a POST request by axios with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a POST request via axios andfirebase cloud function while the body of the request in axios contains data from changes occured in realtime db using the functions but everytime I deploy my code I get the error:

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. 
Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional 
troubleshooting documentation can be found at 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting 
documentation.
```

I am quite new to firebase functions so I really don't know what I am doing here even after having some research.
Code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");



exports.newNodeDetected = functions.database
    .ref("Orders/{userId}/{customerId}/{ordernum}/customername")
    .onCreate((snapchot, context) => {
      const order = snapchot.val();
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      console.log(userId + "AND CUS NAME IS" + order);

      axios.post("http://something.com/data.php", {
        username: userId,
        title: "ttl",
        message: "msg",
      })
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    });
```

Comment: Your code alone will not be able to reproduce that error. Please include your `package.json` in your question so that the community can help you further. Also, try to execute this: `firebase functions:log` on your console and include the logs produced in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone had the same issue. I realized I was running my `npm` commands outside the `functions` folder, therefore the `package.json` wasn't getting edited and my libraries were not really getting downloaded.

Always be careful to use `npm` inside the `functions` folder!!